# nomenclatura envio de form URL

Tags: url

Enviando um formulario o resultado da url enviada é essa:

busca.php?checkin=22%2F12%2F2017&checkout=10%2F01%2F2018

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

busca.php?checkin=16/08/2017&checkout=25/08/2017

Na opinião de vocês, qual a melhor maneira de fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Não há "melhor maneira" pois esse já é o formato correto.

Isso é o chamado "url encoded".

No backend, PHP por exemplo, decodifique com a função [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) se necessário.

Answer (score -1):

No Localizador-Padrão de Recursos (`URL, Uniform Resource Locator`), um endereço na Internet a codificação por cento é utilizada para prevenir a má interpretação dos caracteres especiais, como espaços, parêntesis e outros símbolos. O navegador Web analisa o endereço de localização e codifica/decodifica os caracteres especiais para que tudo funcione adequadamente.

O uso da codificação por cento é necessária nos casos de caracteres não imprimíveis, caracteres fora do padrão ASCII, caracteres reservados à sintaxe de uma URL `("$", "&amp;", "+", ",", "/", ":", ";", "=", "?", "@")` e caracteres inseguros que podem enganar uma URL `(espaço, "&lt;", "&gt;", "#", "%", "{", "}", "|", "\", "^", "~", "[", "]", "`").`

Tabela de caracteres de escape em URL:

```
Caractere    Codificação     Caractere     Codificação

espaço          %20             #             %23
$               %24             %             %25
&amp;           %26             @             %40
`               %60             /             %2F
:               %3A             ;             %3B
&lt;            %3C             =             %3D
&gt;            %3E             ?             %3F
[               %5B             \             %5C
]               %5D             ^             %5E
{               %7B             |             %7C
}               %7D             ~             %7E
+               %2B             ,             %2C
```

Fonte: http://dan-scientia.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/codificacao-por-cento-para-caracteres.html